# How to add google remarketing code for meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, meteor

The seo company I work closely with told me I needed to add this code inbetween the body tags of my meteor project.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 123456789;
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
var google_remarketing_only = true;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"       src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt=""src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/949352235    /?value=0&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

However as we know script tags don't get executed properly inside body tags.
So I searched on google to find an answer and I found this code that supposedly works but it's in REACT. How can I convert this react code into normal javascript that I can refer from a template or something. I'm thinking in a onCreated and or onRendered function.

```
          GoogleTag = React.createClass({
                displayName : 'GoogleTag',
                render(){
                    var src = '';
                    if(this.props.type === 'conversion'){
                        src =  _.template('//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/<%=id%>/?label=<%=label%>&guid=ON&script=0'),
                        src = src({id : this.props.id, label : this.props.label})
                    }

                    if (this.props.type === 'remarketing') {
                        src = _.template('//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/<%=id%>/?value=0&guid=ON&script=0'),
                        src = src({id: this.props.id})
                    }
                    var style = {
                        display : "inline"
                    },
                    imgStyle = {
                        borderStyle : "none"
                    }
                    return (
                        <div style={style}>
                            <img height="1" width="1" style={imgStyle} alt="" src={src}/>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Remarketing library for async actions](https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/asynchronous/#use-with-promises) and write your meta-data via direct call tracking function:

```
/* remarketingTrack utility */

export default function remarketingTrack(data = {}) {
      try {
        trackConversion({
          google_conversion_id: SOME_ID,
          google_custom_params: data,
          google_remarketing_only: true
        });
      } catch (e) {
        // error
      }
 }

/** somewhere in ReactJS component **/

    componentDidMount() {
       remarketingTrack({
         flight_originid: XXX,
         flight_destid: XXX,
         flight_startdate: date,
         flight_pagetype: 'home',
       });
    }
```

I think that it's more flexible and neat solution

Answer (score 0):

Place

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var google_conversion_id = 123456789;
    var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
    var google_remarketing_only = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"></script>
```

in your head and you will be fine.

In Meteor you can only have one `<head>` defined in your project, just create a file called `head.html` on the client and place the code above inside a body tag in the file.

Comment: Hey Lieuwe, thanks for your comment.
I did what you said and put the script tags inside the head and I received this error on my google tag assistant.
http://s11.postimg.org/olv1wnzb7/Screen_Shot_2016_03_16_at_10_30_50_AM.png

Comment: @DCastillo isn't that more like a warning? I have no experience with Google Tag Assistant, but I guess it's saying that because putting a script in the head blocks page rendering. But Meteor does this by default, so that wouldn't be a problem. If you REALLY have to put this in the body, take a look at https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-inject-initial (the Inject.rawBody function specifically)

Comment: So I did what you told me but I'm getting errors left and right , this is what I have so far.
https://gist.github.com/ecuanaso/1dacda120799bad5584b

what do you think I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

First, remove any code that you have regarding this. A standard implementation won't work with Meteor without a custom written implementation.

Second, take the code block that Google gives you. Throw out all of the JavaScript, and all of the script tags. You don't need them.

We'll be running a 'non-standard implementation', but it work's the same as far as we're concerned. Take the code within the `noscript` tags (the div with the img tag), and we need to place it in every place our pages render. So, place it in your Blaze or React layout template, and you should be done.

Google will detect the noscript implementation (which they create so it'll work for visitors who don't have JavaScript enabled, but we are hacking it for use with our implementation), all Google really needs to see is the url call from the img tag :)